# How is javascript used to transfer information between websites

Tags: javascript, json, kissmetrics

I have searched everywhere for a clear and concise answer on how to transfer information between two websites. I want to be able to collect information from a client's websites and record them in my database.

Kissmetrics gives two code snippets like this to embed on your website, with which they use to gather information. I can see they are calling a js script. Is this done using javascript or something else? Any recommended tutorials would be wonderful.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var _kmq = _kmq || [];
function _kms(u){
setTimeout(function(){
var s = document.createElement('script'); var f = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true;
s.src = u; f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);
}, 1);
}
_kms('//i.kissmetrics.com/i.js');_kms('//doug1izaerwt3.cloudfront.net/fbe64b b0f9.1.js');
</script>




_kmq.push(['record', 'Viewed Homepage']);
_kmq.push(['record', 'Signed Up', {'Plan':'Pro', 'Amount':99.95}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are basically creating new script tags on your page and loading their own javascript , so there is no cross domain issues. you are just telling your app to load their javascript and bootstrap their code , nothing special here.

Answer (score 0):

They are dynamically loading two script files, one from the `i.kissmetrics.com domain` and one from `doug1izaerwt3.cloudfront.net`.

Sometimes, the very requesting of the javascript URL causes the server receiving the request to record certain information and sometimes the returned javascript itself turns around and sends more requests that cause the server to record certain information.  We'd have to see these actual scripts to know more specifically what they are doing.

The data pushed into the `_kmq` array is probably data that is queued up to be sent to the kissmetrics server (Google Analytics does something similar).

Comment: Thanks. Here is a link to the Js - http://doug1izaerwt3.cloudfront.net/900df9272abaea4ffbe64bb0e050ae3a054589f9.1.js

Answer (score 0):

JSONP - look into AJAX calls with JSONP as protocol

Comment: JSONP is used to request data, not sending data

Comment: And a JSONP request for data, can ACTUALLY do more than just a request, it can manipulate data as well. It's just a call to a service.

Comment: @Relic any idea of a tutorial i can read about sending data using jsonp. Most of what i am finding are about requesting data.

Comment: well JSONP is just a way to request data, but imagine on the recieving side, it can except get variables. Say ***.com?varA=21. Now the request, goes to the server with that var, and now your response is based off of varA being equal to 21. And in the response the server can also do an action related to varA, and save the value or w/e. The only thing is, you need to have control of both domains to set that up effectively.